# Convert word to ASCII values with Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am new user in python. I would like to convert the word "cook" to the ASCII value. I want to calculate the total number. For e.g. for the word "cook" the total will be (99+210+321+428)=1058. Below is my code :

```
import nltk
s="cook"
sum=0
for c in s:
   x=ord(c)
   sum=sum+x
   print(sum)
```

**Output** :

```
99
210
321
428
```

I want the total (1058). What I have to add more?

Comment: Remove the indentation from the last line. (The total is 99 + 111 + 111 + 107 = 428.)

Comment: The total **is** 428, not 1058.

Comment: @molbdnilo no, that doesn't help. OP's 1058 is simpy wrong

Comment: @MarcusMüller It helps with getting the correct sum, but I admit not much with getting the incorrect one (amended my comment).

Comment: Look, SMO `ord("c")==99`, `ord("o") == 111`, `ord("k")==107`, so 99+111+111+107==428.

Comment: So you might be omitting the **formula** of what you really want to calculate. In that case, we can't help you, SMO. Please add the formula that converts arbitrary words to the sum you want.

Comment: @Marcus Muller ,i want the sum of the ASCII  for the the word "cook",which is 428 you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the formula that you want:

```
x, total = 0, 0
for c in 'cook':
   x += ord(c)
   total += x
print(total)
```

It produces the number you want:

```
1058
```

#### Alternative: using numpy

```
>>> from numpy import sum, cumsum
>>> sum(cumsum([ord(c) for c in 'cook']))
1058
```